# Read atributes from an alembic?

Tags: alembic, custom-attributes

I'm trying to export geometry from Houdini to Blender, as far as I know alembic is the way to go.
But, even tho I have multiple attributes in Houdini, I only receive in Blender the color attribute (Cd), the rest are gone.
I was wondering if there is a way to get those extra attributes inside Blender.